# Simple way to refactor this Python code to reduce repetition

Tags: python-2.7, refactoring

I'd like help refactoring this code to reduce redundant lines/concepts. The code for this def in basically repeated 3 times.

Restrictions: 
- I'm new, so a really fancy list comprehension or turning things into objects with dunders and method overrides is way to advanced for me.
- Built in modules only. This is Pyhton 2.7 code, and only imports os and re.

What the overall script does:
Finds files with a fixed prefix. The files are pipe-delimited text files. The first row is a header. It has a footer which can be 1 or more rows. Based on the prefix, the script throws away "columns" from the text file that aren't needed in another step. It saves the data, comma-separated, in a new file with a .csv extension.

The bulk of the work is done in processRawFiles(). This is what I'd like refactored, since it's wildly repetitive.

```
def separateTranslationTypes(translationFileList):
    '''Takes in list of all files to process and find which are roomtypes
    , ratecodes or sourcecodes. The type of file determines how it will be processed.'''
    rates = []
    rooms = []
    sources = []
    for afile in translationFileList:
        rates.append( [m.group() for m in re.finditer('cf_ratecodeheader+(.*)', afile)] )
        rooms.append( [m.group() for m in re.finditer('cf_roomtypes+(.*)', afile)] )
        sources.append( [m.group() for m in re.finditer('cf_sourcecodes+(.*)', afile)] )
    # empty list equates to False. So if x is True if the list is not empty - thus kept.
    rates = [x[0] for x in rates if x]
    rooms = [x[0] for x in rooms if x]
    sources = [x[0] for x in sources if x]
    print '... rateCode files :: ',rates,'\n'
    print '... roomType files :: ',rooms,'\n'
    print '... sourceCode files :: ',sources, '\n'

    return {'rateCodeFiles':rates,
            'roomTypeFiles':rooms,
            'sourceCodeFiles':sources}

groupedFilestoProcess = separateTranslationTypes(allFilestoProcess)


def processRawFiles(groupedFileDict):
    for key in groupedFileDict:
        # Process the rateCodes file
        if key == 'rateCodeFiles':
            for fname_Value in groupedFileDict[key]: # fname_Value is the filename
                if os.path.exists(fname_Value):
                    workingfile = open(fname_Value,'rb')
                    filedatastring = workingfile.read() # turns entire file contents to a single string
                    workingfile.close()
                    outname = 'forUpload_' + fname_Value[:-4:] + '.csv' # removes .txt of any other 3 char extension
                    outputfile = open(outname,'wb')
                    filedatalines = filedatastring.split('\n') # a list containing each line of the file
                    rawheaders = filedatalines[0] # 1st element of the list is the first row of the file, with the headers
                    parsedheaders = rawheaders.split('|') # turn the header string into a list where | was delimiter
                    print '\n'
                    print 'outname: ', outname, '\n'
                    # print 'rawheaders: ', rawheaders, '\n'
                    # print 'parsedheaders: ',parsedheaders, '\n'
                    # print filedatalines[0:2]
                    print '\n'
                    ratecodeindex = parsedheaders.index('RATE_CODE')
                    ratecodemeaning = parsedheaders.index('DESCRIPTION')
                    for dataline in filedatalines:
                        if dataline[:4] == 'LOGO':
                            firstuselessline = filedatalines.index(dataline)
                            # print firstuselessline
                    # ignore the first line which was the headers
                    # stop before the line that starts with LOGO - the first useless line
                    for dataline in filedatalines[1:firstuselessline-1:]:
                        # print dataline.split('|')
                        theratecode = dataline.split('|')[ratecodeindex]
                        theratemeaning = dataline.split('|')[ratecodemeaning]
                        # print theratecode, '\t', theratemeaning, '\n'
                        linetowrite = theratecode + ',' + theratemeaning + '\n'
                        outputfile.write(linetowrite)
                    outputfile.close()

        # Process the roomTypes file
        if key == 'roomTypeFiles':
            for fname_Value in groupedFileDict[key]: # fname_Value is the filename
                if os.path.exists(fname_Value):
                    workingfile = open(fname_Value,'rb')
                    filedatastring = workingfile.read() # turns entire file contents to a single string
                    workingfile.close()
                    outname = 'forUpload_' + fname_Value[:-4:] + '.csv' # removes .txt of any other 3 char extension
                    outputfile = open(outname,'wb')
                    filedatalines = filedatastring.split('\n') # a list containing each line of the file
                    rawheaders = filedatalines[0] # 1st element of the list is the first row of the file, with the headers
                    parsedheaders = rawheaders.split('|') # turn the header string into a list where | was delimiter
                    print '\n'
                    print 'outname: ', outname, '\n'
                    # print 'rawheaders: ', rawheaders, '\n'
                    # print 'parsedheaders: ',parsedheaders, '\n'
                    # print filedatalines[0:2]
                    print '\n'
                    ratecodeindex = parsedheaders.index('LABEL')
                    ratecodemeaning = parsedheaders.index('SHORT_DESCRIPTION')
                    for dataline in filedatalines:
                        if dataline[:4] == 'LOGO':
                            firstuselessline = filedatalines.index(dataline)
                            # print firstuselessline
                    # ignore the first line which was the headers
                    # stop before the line that starts with LOGO - the first useless line
                    for dataline in filedatalines[1:firstuselessline-1:]:
                        # print dataline.split('|')
                        theratecode = dataline.split('|')[ratecodeindex]
                        theratemeaning = dataline.split('|')[ratecodemeaning]
                        # print theratecode, '\t', theratemeaning, '\n'
                        linetowrite = theratecode + ',' + theratemeaning + '\n'
                        outputfile.write(linetowrite)
                    outputfile.close()
        # Process sourceCodes file
        if key == 'sourceCodeFiles':
            for fname_Value in groupedFileDict[key]: # fname_Value is the filename
                if os.path.exists(fname_Value):
                    workingfile = open(fname_Value,'rb')
                    filedatastring = workingfile.read() # turns entire file contents to a single string
                    workingfile.close()
                    outname = 'forUpload_' + fname_Value[:-4:] + '.csv' # removes .txt of any other 3 char extension
                    outputfile = open(outname,'wb')
                    filedatalines = filedatastring.split('\n') # a list containing each line of the file
                    rawheaders = filedatalines[0] # 1st element of the list is the first row of the file, with the headers
                    parsedheaders = rawheaders.split('|') # turn the header string into a list where | was delimiter
                    print '\n'
                    print 'outname: ', outname, '\n'
                    # print 'rawheaders: ', rawheaders, '\n'
                    # print 'parsedheaders: ',parsedheaders, '\n'
                    # print filedatalines[0:2]
                    print '\n'
                    ratecodeindex = parsedheaders.index('SOURCE_CODE')
                    ratecodemeaning = parsedheaders.index('DESCRIPTION')
                    for dataline in filedatalines:
                        if dataline[:4] == 'LOGO':
                            firstuselessline = filedatalines.index(dataline)
                            # print firstuselessline
                    # ignore the first line which was the headers
                    # stop before the line that starts with LOGO - the first useless line
                    for dataline in filedatalines[1:firstuselessline-1:]:
                        # print dataline.split('|')
                        theratecode = dataline.split('|')[ratecodeindex]
                        theratemeaning = dataline.split('|')[ratecodemeaning]
                        # print theratecode, '\t', theratemeaning, '\n'
                        linetowrite = theratecode + ',' + theratemeaning + '\n'
                        outputfile.write(linetowrite)
                    outputfile.close()

processRawFiles(groupedFilestoProcess)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to redo my code because there was a new incident where the files in question neither had the header row, nor the footer row. However, since the columns I want still occur in the same order I can keep them only. Also, we stop reading if any next row has fewer columns than the larger of the two indices used.

As for reducing repetition, `processRawFiles` contains two `def`'s that remove the need to repeat a lot of that parsing code from before.

```
def separateTranslationTypes(translationFileList):
    '''Takes in list of all files to process and find which are roomtypes
    , ratecodes or sourcecodes. The type of file determines how it will be processed.'''
    rates = []
    rooms = []
    sources = []
    for afile in translationFileList:
        rates.append( [m.group() for m in re.finditer('cf_ratecode+(.*)', afile)] )
        rooms.append( [m.group() for m in re.finditer('cf_roomtypes+(.*)', afile)] )
        sources.append( [m.group() for m in re.finditer('cf_sourcecodes+(.*)', afile)] )
    # empty list equates to False. So if x is True if the list is not empty - thus kept.
    rates = [x[0] for x in rates if x]
    rooms = [x[0] for x in rooms if x]
    sources = [x[0] for x in sources if x]
    print '... rateCode files :: ',rates,'\n'
    print '... roomType files :: ',rooms,'\n'
    print '... sourceCode files :: ',sources, '\n'

    return {'rateCodeFiles':rates,
            'roomTypeFiles':rooms,
            'sourceCodeFiles':sources}

groupedFilestoProcess = separateTranslationTypes(allFilestoProcess)

def processRawFiles(groupedFileDict):
    def someFixedProcess(bFileList, codeIndex, codeDescriptionIndex):
        for fname_Value in bFileList: # fname_Value is the filename
            if os.path.exists(fname_Value):
                workingfile = open(fname_Value,'rb')
                filedatastring = workingfile.read() # turns entire file contents to a single string
                workingfile.close()
                outname = 'forUpload_' + fname_Value[:-4:] + '.csv' # removes .txt of any other 3 char extension
                outputfile = open(outname,'wb')
                filedatalines = filedatastring.split('\n') # a list containing each line of the file
                # print '\n','outname: ',outname,'\n\n'
                # HEADERS ARE NOT IGNORED! Since the file might not have headers.
                print outname
                for dataline in filedatalines:
                    # print filedatalines.index(dataline), dataline.split('|')
                    # e.g. index 13, reuires len 14, so len > index is needed
                    if len(dataline.split('|')) > codeDescriptionIndex:
                        thecode_text = dataline.split('|')[codeIndex]
                        thedescription_text = dataline.split('|')[codeDescriptionIndex]
                        linetowrite = thecode_text + ',' + thedescription_text + '\n'
                        outputfile.write(linetowrite)
                    outputfile.close()

    def processByType(aFileList, itsType):
        typeDict = {'rateCodeFiles' : {'CODE_INDEX': 4,'DESC_INDEX':7},
                    'roomTypeFiles' : {'CODE_INDEX': 1,'DESC_INDEX':13},
                    'sourceCodeFiles': {'CODE_INDEX': 2,'DESC_INDEX':3}}
        # print 'someFixedProcess(',aFileList,typeDict[itsType]['CODE_INDEX'],typeDict[itsType]['DESC_INDEX'],')'
        someFixedProcess(aFileList,
                         typeDict[itsType]['CODE_INDEX'],
                         typeDict[itsType]['DESC_INDEX'])

    for key in groupedFileDict:
        processByType(groupedFileDict[key],key)

processRawFiles(groupedFilestoProcess)
```